# Why is our LaTeX math support so different from that of MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, math

As far as I learned from [this topic](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/873), both CSTheory & MathOverflow use MathJax. In addition, when I checked the version, I noticed that both use v1.0.1.

However, the math rendering experience is quite different on TCS & MO: while the former takes a (considerable) time to render a formula, the latter works on the fly (especially while entering a question or answer).

Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: have you asked this on meta.SO ? that seems like a place where you might get an answer.

Comment: Good call! First, I mistakenly asked it on MO (http://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/705/), then a user point out the mistake and so I asked it on SO (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67258/151887). I hope they don't close it as off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is provided by KennyTM here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67258#67261.

Comment: excellent. now you can accept your own answer :)

Comment: @Suresh: LOL! Anyway, KennyTM's answer leaves open the possibility of improving TCS. It concludes that "no SE overlord confirmed whether it is [status-declined] or [status-planned]". Unfortunately, I am very new to the SE world. Do you (or any other Gurus) know whether there is anything we can do about this?

Comment: maybe post a request on meta.SO and see if we can get some SE love for it

Comment: @Suresh: I just posted one there, and got the aforementioned answer. Dunno how to start it over :(